# Unity Tutorial Instantiate giving UnassignedReferenceError

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I believe I have followed the introductory breakout tutorial exactly and everything is working except the particles on brick destruction which give an error on the Instantiate call.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Bricks : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject brickParticle;

    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision other)
    {
        Instantiate(brickParticle, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        GM.instance.DestroyBrick();
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

I am very new to unity and have been able to get any Prefabs to work due to this confusion.

The error I get whenever a collision occurs is: UnassignedReferenceException: The variable brickParticle of Bricks has not been assigned.

My understanding was that the entire purpose of Instantiate is to create a new object so I am a bit baffled.  The tutorial in question is here: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/creating-a-breakout-game?playlist=17219

Is it possible some update to unity has changed the requirements?

Comment: You haven't assigned anything to `brickParticle`. You need to make sure it's referencing something, for example, a prefab. You can assign the reference in the inspector in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [Unity Inspector](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Inspector.html), Where you have attached your Bricks Script you can see **brickParticle None (GameObject)**. Just Drag and Drop your Prefab onto this area to assign the prefab to this variable and try running your game. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[UnityEngine.Instantiate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) makes a copy of an `Object` (not to be confused with `GameObject`). So you pass in an already instantiated prefab to `Instantiate` and it will make a copy for you. `brickParticle` likely needs to have the prefab assigned to it before runtime in the inspector window for the `GameObject` that has the `Bricks` script on it.

Because `Instantiate` returns a copy, you may want to store the return result if you need to retain a reference to it:

```
GameObject newBrickParticle = Instantiate(brickParticle, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

However, if the particle prefab is set up to fire and forget (meaning it would delete itself automatically after some time), then you probably don't need to keep a reference of it around.

Comment: Sorry, I am totally new to unity, how do I assign a prefab to a variable that is declared in a script with the inspector?

Comment: In the Inspector for that script you'll see 'brickParticle' as a field, since it's a public variable in the 'Bricks' script. You simply drag the particles prefab onto that field and it will save that information the prefab that has the script on it, when that script loads you'll be able to use 'brickParticle'.